# Login test passes with wrong credentials

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Anyone know what is wrong with this code.
It passes my test even if i have wrong credentials.
I am using Java and Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse.

Am not sure what am doing wrong and cannot seem to find answers on Google.

```
public class LoginTest {

    String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://CODESV3;databaseName=Codes;integratedSecurity=true";
    String DBdriver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    Connection conn = null;
    WebDriver driver = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;


    @BeforeTest
    public void establishConn()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://10.10.10.50/");
        // establish connection 
        try{
            Class.forName(DBdriver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database failed to connect ");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin()
    {
        String forceID="1234";
        String username="ayaslem";
        String password="Delpiero10+";
        boolean valueFound=false;
        // Check the db
        try{
            pstmt=conn.prepareCall("select * from Login where ForceID=? and Username=? and Password=?");
            pstmt.setString(2,forceID);
            pstmt.setString(3,username);
            pstmt.setString(4,password);
            rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            valueFound =rs.next();

        }catch(Exception e){
                // report some error
        }
        // login into app
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_OrganisationName']")).sendKeys(forceID);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_UserId']")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_Password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/form/div/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/input")).click();
}
```

Comment: You don't do anything with valueFound?

Comment: what am i expecting to do with valueFound? is set as false, valueFound =rs.next(); should return false if value do not match the db and true if matches the db

Comment: yes but you don't test it from what I can see? You just set it by rs.next(). Theres no assertion or check of whether its true or not. You just come out of the try block and log in to the app regardless of the value of valueFound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not do any checks or assertion on valueFound. I don't know what your using to Test it, but can you do something similar to

```
assertTrue(valueFound);
```

or

```
if(valueFound) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_OrganisationName']")).sendKeys(forceID);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_UserId']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_Password']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/form/div/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/input")).click();
} else {
    //dont login
}
```

Comment: Stu Whyte, your code is valid but i want my code to go to the site and  enter the credentials regardless of right or wrong credentials. Then to check if the credentials entered is in the db, pass the test if not fail the test.

Comment: I do not understand you. This code goes in the method annotated as @Test. Which is what i assume the method which you mean fails. This code goes at the bottom of the method, so after its checked the credentials in the DB...

Comment: Thank you Stu Whyte, managed to get it working. i compared page title after the code and its working fine.